# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined inside v-for

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

`console.log(this.sights)` returns an array with 20 objects that have a couple of properties like `name`, `photos`, `references`, etc. Currently I am trying to loop through these objects and display their `name`s and their `photo_reference`s. I do this like this:

```
<div @click='selectSight(index)' v-for='(sight, index) in sights'>
    {{ sight.name }}
    {{ sight.photos[0].photo_reference }}
</div>
```

This displays the `sight.name`. However, I get an error

> "Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"".

I tried manually accessing like this:

```
console.log(this.sights[0].photos[0].photo_reference)
```

and it returns the `photo_reference`. So, I'm not mistaking the properties. So what am I doing wrong?

This is the array structure:

```
(20) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, __ob__: Observer]
    0:
        geometry: Object
        icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/museum-71.png"
        id: "975708e853f136200f2229c793df9070707b842e"
        name: "National Museum of Modern Art, Tokyo"
        opening_hours: Object
        photos: Array(1)
            0:
                height: 3456
                html_attributions: Array(1)
                photo_reference: "CmRZAAAA60seVRHbzyg3TPIUPEUaDbzI2-TpMB3cB3bC8BYG_gRrJwmwSVY1Mcl1PBo0U0CMwmqssyQw4w2iHyh6ze3iQaiXdsveolGBovi3rGZTgvKjTV9PRt-WDieYrwoRy1z0EhBsZitey_MyjiwrYK_Sol3eGhSfOpXUpLc-3RYeJjz2JKMMXYNZYw"
                width: 4608
```

Comment: Where does the array come from?

Comment: It's probably because you only tested `sights[0]` - the property must be missing from another member of the array.

Comment: There must be some `sight` which has `photos` set to `undefined`. Check the entire `sights` array

Comment: Don't forget; opening the object like that in the console only gets you the value at the time you clicked the down arrow. Most of the time, this is a timing thing. I don't know vue, but you should be able to echo `JSON.stringify(sights)` before that line in the HTML.

Comment: The array comes from Google Maps API. I'm gonna check if there's an object that has empty photos.

Comment: Yes, it seems some places don't have photos property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting that error because some of the objects have `sight.photos` as `undefined`. You could add a check like this before accessing the zeroth index:

```
<div @click='selectSight(index)' v-for='(sight, index) in sights'>
    {{ sight.name }}
    {{ sight.photos && sight.photos.length > 0 ? sight.photos[0].photo_reference : '' }}
</div>
```